# Read Feature flags from AppConfiguration in a Custom Nuget package

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-app-configuration

I'm trying to read my feature flags stored in an AppConfiguration.
My goal is to create my own NuGet package to reuse it later in several projects. this way I don't need to change the code.

It's all good when I read the settings from "Configuration Explorer" but I can't read the feature flags.

Appreciate any comment.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can read feature flags programmatically using App Configuration SDK. Here is some sample code:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/appconfiguration/Azure.Data.AppConfiguration/samples/Sample9_FeatureFlags.md

Comment: I have already tried but where is the "FeatureFlagConfigurationSetting"

Comment: It's a type defined in the SDK:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/appconfiguration/Azure.Data.AppConfiguration/src/FeatureFlagConfigurationSetting.cs